# Should I Allow access to public API without token or with token

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring security and we use a token to authenticate and authorize the user once it is authenticated. There are some APIs that will be used by our website visitor as well.

Should I allow the visitor to access these APIs by providing a public token (this public token will be accessed by hitting a particular URL)

OR

Should I allow the visitor to access the APIs without any token?

What is the best approach?

Comment: If you need to keep track of what every unique API user is doing, yes, otherwise I think it's useless...

Answer (score 1):

If u are trying to provide a public key(or a token) to access a non Secure API that is completely useless. Just try to exclude them from Spring Security.

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/publicApis/*").permitAll()
```

If u are more concerned about Security attacks like Man In Middle then u might want to consider securing the Public APIs with API signing mechanisms (Hash/Digest) based mechanisms to create signatures for the request. This will avoid request tampering.

Answer (score 1):

As n00dl3 said, it depends on whether or not you care what every user is doing to your site. That being said, if you care, keep in mind that there is no surefire way to track each anonymous user for security purposes.

Anonymous users can always find a way to spoof whatever you're using to track them, be it IP, cookies, user-agent etc. Even if you give them a token, they can always request a new one every amount of time to mask their activity.